# Elasticsearch facets comes as whitespace tokenized

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping for elasticsearch

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "hotel": {
            'properties': {"name": {
                "type": "string",
                "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
                "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer"},

            "destination": {'properties': {'en': {
                "type": "string",
                "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
                "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer"}}},

            "country": {"properties": {"en": {
                "type": "string",
                "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
                "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer"}}},
            "destination_facets": {"properties": {"en": {
                "type": "string",
                "search_analyzer": "facet_analyzer"
            }}}

            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "str_search_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                },

                "str_index_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "substring"]
                },
                "facet_analyzer": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword"
                },
            },

            "filter": {
                "substring": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which I want my destination_facets to be not tokenized. But it comes as white-space tokenized. Is there a way to ignore all token activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set your `facet_analyzer` not only for the `search_analyzer` but also for the `index_analyzer` (Elasticsearch probably use this one for facetting, the `search_analyzer` is only used to parse query strings).

Note that if you want the same analyze for both, you can just use the name `analyzer` in your mapping.

Ex :

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "hotel": {
        ...
        "destination_facets": {"properties": {"en": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "facet_analyzer"
        }}}

        }
    }
},
"settings": {
    ...
}
```

}

Comment: If I may add some detail. The search analyzer is used when executing queries that support text analysis, not only query_string. You do have to change the index_analyzer in this case because what you show when faceting is what you indexed, and in order to index it you apply text analysis to it. The analyzer used at index time is the index_analyzer.